# Best performance and maintenance pattern for store hierarchical data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tree

What is the best and the worst in context of performance and maintenance for working with tree stuctures:

- ltree
- Recursive queries
- Closure Table + Adjacency List pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on the usage patterns.    Are you looking to query a parent and all of its descendants, or just immediate descendants? If looking for all of the rows below, a self-referencing table, using nested sets is likely best.   If you want only one layer, the storage and maintenance of the nested sets are not needed, and instead, just index the parent key.

Please note that due to seek times, linked lists will be much more efficient on SSD than spinning disc, if you decide to use adjacency.